# Can't transfer data from one phone to another using data cable

Tags: usb-on-the-go

When I connect two phones using data cable and otg they charge but no data transfer option comes.One is Android 6 and other 7.Earlier 2 or more years ago I tried doing it and it was successful but now it only charges.